# Importing the right files to use firebase's Realtime Database in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase's Realtime Database in React. I've successfully used it before in the regular browser. What I seem to be struggling on is this:

In a regular browser, these two scripts were needed:

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

I think I'm successfully importing the first tag like this: `import firebase from "firebase/app";` But for the second one, I don't actually know what to write. See a copy of my code below:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import * as database from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //successfully written
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebase.database();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers) for using module bundlers.  All you do is import the per-product SDK without assigning names or variables.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebase.database();
```

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. You made an error - just have to remove 'from'. Then I will accept your answer

Comment: @tonitone120 In the future, consider making such an edit to an answer yourself. If you find a problem in an answer, you can edit. That's one of the many wonders if Stack Overflow's wiki-like philosophy.